# Ubuntu not booting after using Ubuntu-Tweak's janitor function

Tags: 12.04, boot, ubuntu-tweak

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. This morning my Ubuntu 12.04 would not boot up properly anymore.
After the loading screen saying "Ubuntu" with the five little dots it just goes black and nothing happens.

The only remarkable change I made yesterday was installing Ubuntu-Tweak and using the Janitor to clean my system. I've tried the dpkg option in the recovery menu, but that didn't help. Any advice what else I can try?

Comment: Maybe these help: [Ubuntuforums link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1925476) [Askubuntu link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134575/unity-will-not-boot-12-04)

Comment: @Jobob Can you please provide the answer you found on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you happened to have edited/modified/deleted something related to X.org then the answer provided by [Jobob](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/ubuntu-tiphow-to-removeinstall-and-reconfigure-xorg-without-reinstalling-ubuntu.html) will help:

1. Remove existing xorg using the following command

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg
   ```
2. Install xorg using the following command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
   ```
3. Reconfigure xorg using the following command

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
   ```

And if you have an Nvidia or Ati card, I would also suggest to reinstall the driver as shown in [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/driver-to-use-when-installing-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card)